# Substitution rule on maple

Tags: substitution, maple

I am slightly new to maple and I am interested in the following question.

Let's assume I have a map f that sends a to abb and b to a. My first question is how do I define this map on maple? I am also interested in when the map is applied repeated i.e. the iterates of f. Say if I have a seed ab, is there something I can put on maple such that when I apply f, it becomes abba and so on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
> f(a) := a,b,b;
                            a, b, b
> f(b) := a;
                               a
> map(f, [a, b]);
                          [a, b, b, a]
> map(f, %);
                    [a, b, b, a, a, a, b, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using strings.

```
restart:

g := e->StringTools:-SubstituteAll(StringTools:-CharacterMap("ab","ta",e),"t","abb"):

g("a");
                                "abb"

g("b");
                                 "a"

g("ab");
                               "abba"

(g@@2)("ab");
                             "abbaaabb"

subs(["a"=a,"b"=b],StringTools:-Explode(g("ab")));
                            [a, b, b, a]

f(a) := a,b,b;
                           f(a) := a, b, b

f(b) := a;
                              f(b) := a

map(f, [a, b]);
                            [a, b, b, a]

map(f, %);
                      [a, b, b, a, a, a, b, b]

F := e->map(f,e):

F([a, b]);
                            [a, b, b, a]

(F@@2)([a, b]);
                      [a, b, b, a, a, a, b, b]

evalb( subs(["a"=a,"b"=b],StringTools:-Explode(g("ab"))) = F([a, b]) );
                                true

ans1 := CodeTools:-Usage( (g@@20)("ab") ):
memory used=6.01MiB, alloc change=4.01MiB, cpu time=100.00ms, real time=102.00ms, gc time=0ns

ans1list := CodeTools:-Usage( subs(["a"=a,"b"=b],StringTools:-Explode(ans1)) ):
memory used=32.00MiB, alloc change=32.01MiB, cpu time=170.00ms, real time=175.00ms, gc time=0ns

ans2 := CodeTools:-Usage( (F@@20)([a, b]) ):
memory used=128.11MiB, alloc change=21.02MiB, cpu time=3.81s, real time=3.82s, gc time=3.46s

evalb( ans1list = ans2 );
                                true
```

You could also write either `g` or `F` to chew on larger chunks (of length 2, or 4, etc), and to recursively split the argument, etc, and even to learn such patterns.